# How to remove Sox dependency on ffmpeg in Yocto

Tags: dependencies, yocto

In my embedded application I have to downsample wav files.
I found out that SoX could do the job so I added it in my image recipe.

When building the image it raised an error as ffmpeg is required as dependency, so I added ffmpeg in my recipe

Then it raised the following error :

```
ffmpeg was skipped: because it has a restricted license 'commercial'. Which is not whitelisted in LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST
```

So I ended up adding LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST="commercial" in my conf/local.conf file. Then it builds.

However, I only use a downsampling function of SoX and **I would like to get rid of ffmpeg constraints**.

The version of SoX embedded is 14.4.2 and, in the recipe, I can see the dependency with ffmpeg and the fact that LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST must contain "commercial"

On yocto/meta-openembedded I found the recipe for version 14.4.0 of SoX and it does not depends on ffmpeg.

I have two possibilities though I do not know how to implement them:

1. embed version 14.4.0 of SoX, which seems to be the simplest solution (hoping that it won't raise other issues),
2. overload the current recipe in order to compile SoX with the option --with-ffmpeg=no to get rid of ffmpeg

my image recipe starts like this:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL = " \
packagegroup-core-boot \
packagegroup-verbatim-sensor \
python3 \
python3-pillow \
sox \
ffmpeg\
${CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL} \
"
...
```

How can I include a particular version of a recipe for SoX ?

How can I overload the recipe sox_14.4.2.bb to get rid of ffmpeg ?

**EDIT :** I forgot to mention that my Yocto is based on branch "Honister" which takes sox 14.4.2 by default

**EDIT :** I'm a Yocto beginner so I may say something stupid but would it work if I'd take the content of sox_14.4.0.bb and use it in a .bbappend to override sox_14.4.2.bb ?
I tried but it fails on parsing.

**EDIT :** well, after further research it turns out that sox relies on libav functions for resampling, which is the function I need.
In sox 14.4.0, libav is reffered to directly, but in sox 14.4.2 libav is provided by ffmpeg (ffmpeg 4.4)
So I'd like to try another approach that consists of doing a ffmpeg_4.4.bbappend in which I neutralize the unwanted packages (that require commercial license) and also the "commercial" license but I'm not sure how to proceed.
Shall I do a PACKAGE_EXCLUDE line with the packages ?
How can I remove the LICENSE_FLAGS from ffmpeg_4.4.bb through a .bbappend ?